# Can't get access to my internal IIS Server?

Tags: networking, ip-address, iis, windows-server-2012

Before I could get access to my IIS Server using its static private IP address (on the Windows Server 2012 itself), but now I can only access the IIS Server web page using its localhost and 12.0.0.1 addresses?

I binded the static address to the port, but still no access. Firewall allows the port (which was configured before, though its on the Server itself anyway).

Can anyone identify why I can't access the IIS Server within in the Server using its static IP address?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using the 127.0.0.1 address it goes to the same place as your local intranet address